# Magento 1.9 header.phtml file is not reading

Tags: magento-1.9

In my Magento 1.9 platform . I have made my /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/MyPackage/MyTheme/template/header.phml . But the Magento is not reading my header file . I just want to know from where localhost is taking the header file.
It is not reading my header.phtml file , it is reading the same file but from any another path.  But I dont know from where it is taking my Header.phtml content

Answer (score 0):

```
app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\page\html\header.phtml
```

To override this create copy file from rwd theme and paste in your theme like this-

```
app\design\frontend\MyPackage\MyTheme\template\page\html\header.phtml
```